# Can I keep alpha or beta version when I release productive one?

Tags: android, release, alpha, developer-console

I have uploaded a new alpha version of my Android app in the developer console, which provides a new database version. Now I also have to update the productive release, because of an error - but do not want to include the other stuff of the alpha version into it yet (espacially the database changes).

But if I update the productive track, it normaly replaces the alpha version and this will make the testing version no more available for the testers. Is there any way to release an productive version and keep the alpha one? Or is the only way to relase a new alpha version after the production version and hope that it will be earlier available for the testers than the productive one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but requires to assign the new production versionCode to be both higher than the current production versionCode and lower than the alpha versionCode.

Example:

- Prod versionCode: 100
- Alpha versionCode: 105

=> Use 101 for the new prod versionCode.

If you used consecutive numbers between the production track and the alpha track, then you'll first need to upload a new version on the alpha track with a versionCode a few numbers higher to leave enough room to then assign a lower versionCode for your next version on the production track.

Example:

- Prod versionCode: 100
- Alpha versionCode: 101

=> Publish new APK on alpha track with versionCode 103, then publish new APK on prod track with versionCode 102.

Comment: That's pretty cool, I did not know about that or found this tip somewhere else - thank you very much!!!